# MongoDB find string containing parentheses

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nosql, mean-stack

I am querying MongoDB from Node.js Express API.
I am trying to find a row in which the field current box.profile.description is '(THE'.
using the following code. It doesn't work. I have used regex like using /. That didn't help either

> db.getCollection('content').find({'currentBox.profile.description':
>   '(The'}).

Any thoughts?

Comment: It is indeed straight forward to search for a string that has both open and close parenthesis. The problem is with this single open parenthesis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the `$regex` operator and escaping the parentheses with a double backslash:

```
db.content.find({ 'currentBox.profile.description': { $regex: '\\(The' } });
```

Answer (score 1):

When you tried to use regex, did you include the `$regex` operator and make sure to escape the left parenthesis with a backward slash?

The following code should do the trick.

**Edit:** The backslash character \ in the $regex string must itself be escaped. This is because the JavaScript parser consumes it first, before MongoDB's regex parser sees it. Thus the double backslash.

```
db.getCollection("content").find(
  { "currentBox.profile.description": { $regex: /\\(THE/, $options: "i" } }
)
```

I'm using the `$options` operator to make the match case-insensitive, as it's not clear from your post whether you're searching for `"(THE"` or `"(The"`.

Comment: Thanks for helping but it didn't work. If I use just the opening parentheses without any following characters it works.db.getCollection("content").find(
  { "currentBox.profile.description": { $regex: /\(/, $options: "i" } }
)